# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to scrap a picture from the link and put it into a image file. The request response is returning a byte stream. So I am using decode('utf-8') to convert to unicode stream however, I am facing the following error:

print (info.decode(('utf-8')))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

```
    from urllib import request
    img = request.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg')
    fhand = open('cover.jpg', 'w')
    size = 0
    while True:
        info = img.read(100000)
        if len(info) < 1 : break
        size = size + len(info)
        print (info.decode(('utf-8')))
        fhand.write(info.decode(('utf-8')))

    print (size,'characters copied.')
    fhand.close()
```

Please let me know how can I proceed. Thanks.

Comment: The stream contains a byte with hexadecimal value `ff`, which isn't valid UTF8. So you get an error. Perhaps it's something else?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert it to a Unicode stream? Leave it as a byte stream.

Comment: Oh wait, it's probably a byte order mark...

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: no. If it is, the file is not UTF8 but Unicode16 or -32. Also technically, there should not be a byte order mark in a UTF8 file anyway. Even if there is (some editors do this), it should be correctly encoded.

Comment: Its a binary jpg image, not a string. You shouldn't try to decode it to text. Its not liky you'll get a description of the image or something. BTW, open the target in binary also `open('cover.jpg', 'wb')`.

Comment: @Mark if I leave it as a byte stream and write it to a file I get this error:          TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Comment: @tdelaney could you elaborate please?

Comment: Its a binary stream and should be written to the file without conversion. `decode` is for text data that needs to be converted from the stream representation of text (utf-8 is common on web pages) to the internal representation used by python. If you open the target `"wb"` you can write the binary data directly without the TypeError.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file should be opened in binary mode and then you can copy the stream byte for byte. Since `shutil` already has a handy helper utility, you can

```
import shutil
import os
from urllib import request

img = request.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg')
with open('cover.jpg', 'wb') as fhand:
    shutil.copyfileobj(img, fhand)
print(os.stat('cover.jpg').st_size, 'characters copied')
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Unicode transformations for JPG images.

Unicode is for text. What you are downloading is not text, it is something else.

Try this:

```
from urllib import request
img = request.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg')
fhand = open('cover.jpg', 'wb')
size = 0
while True:
    info = img.read(100000)
    if len(info) < 1 : break
    size = size + len(info)
    fhand.write(info)

print (size,'characters copied.')
```

Or, more simply:

```
from urllib import request
request.urlretrieve('http://www.py4inf.com/cover.jpg', 'cover.jpg')
```