# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte - even though I opened the file in mode 'rb'

Tags: python, http, server

I'm trying to write an HTTP server, but it doesn't matter.
When I try to decode an image data (after writing 'data = file.read()', it gives an error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

I opened the file in 'rb' mode.
Other people usually open the file in 'r' mode and that causes the error. But what is the error here?

What is the problem???

```
def get_content_file(file_path):
    """
    Gets a full path to a file and returns the content of it.
    file_path must be a valid path.
    :param file_path: str (path)
    :return: str (data)
    """

    print(file_path)
    file = open(file_path, 'rb')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    return data.decode()
```

Comment: "When I try to decode an image data" what do you mean? You mean the file is in some image format? Why would you *expect* that to be decodable into utf-8?

Comment: Can you please provide example of image data? Images are encoded using `base64` encoding scheme. Maybe you can try `data.decode('base64')`?

Comment: Error that you get means that encoding to `utf-8` failed, so either it was encoded using another encoding scheme or file was corrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184692/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-invalid)

Comment: The file is a jpg image. I open the img using 'file = open(file_path, 'rb')' and then reading the data like so 'data = file.read()'. I need to use utf-8, for a specific client. The data looks like: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest that you confirm the encoding format of 'file_path'. Download and open the file with Notepad++, check the lower right corner; there you can see whether your file was encoded in the compatible format, or if it has the Byte Order Marker or BOM sign, if either of these is true, simply 'save as' -the correct/required format.